# displaying image metadata in Tex or LaTex

Tags: metadata, xmp

Hi I've been struggling with a Floss solution to showing keywords or descriptions of an image as a caption beneath it.

My particular use case is that I have a folder of hundreds of images, I use on average 40 of these images at a time that will be laid out for printing. I don't want to manually input a description or keyword for each image as this is already part of the image metadata. Is there a way to display the image metadata in Tex or LaTex?

Comment: What do you want to display and how do you want it displayed?

Comment: Well, I don't have access to these [Tugboat issue](https://www.tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb36-3/tb114scarso.pdf) but the title is promising. `luatex` and [`graphicsmagick`](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) could probably work together and extract the EXIF information.

Comment: @jon what I want to display is content of the description field from the Exif or Xmp as a caption. How challenging would it be to do this?

Comment: Relatively easy if you are certain that the field is included. (Many(?) .jpgs on my cpu seem to not have a description field by default.) Extract information into separate files similar to David's command (e.g., `for i in *.jpg; do identify -verbose $i | grep filename | tr -d ' ' | cut -d : -f 2 > $i.desc ; done`), then write a command that includes the `.jpg` and the `.desc` file.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly but there are lots of tools to extract exif (or other metadata).

For example imagemagic `identify`

So (using bash as an example command line)

```sh
for i in *.jpg ; do identify -format '%[EXIF:*]' $i | sed -e 's/exif\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\\def\\exif\1{\2}/' > ${i/jpg/exif}; done
```

will leave a foo.exif file in tex format for each foo.jpg in the current directory.

Taking a random picture I have here

```
$ head -20 P1100279.exif 
\def\exif:Artist{}
\def\exif:ColorSpace{1}
\def\exif:ComponentsConfiguration{1, 2, 3, 0}
\def\exif:CompressedBitsPerPixel{4/1}
\def\exif:Contrast{0}
\def\exif:CustomRendered{0}
\def\exif:DateTime{2014:08:02 11:37:21}
\def\exif:DateTimeDigitized{2014:08:02 11:37:21}
\def\exif:DateTimeOriginal{2014:08:02 11:37:21}
\def\exif:DigitalZoomRatio{0/10}
\def\exif:ExifImageLength{3672}
\def\exif:ExifImageWidth{4896}
\def\exif:ExifOffset{728}
\def\exif:ExifVersion{48, 50, 51, 48}
\def\exif:ExposureBiasValue{0/100}
\def\exif:ExposureMode{0}
\def\exif:ExposureProgram{2}
\def\exif:ExposureTime{10/600}
\def\exif:FileSource{3}
\def\exif:Flash{16}
```

so then you could use

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{P1100279}
\catcode`\:=11 % make : a letter
\input{P1100279}

I took this picture on \exif:DateTimeOriginal
\end{figure}
```

which will print

> I took this picture on 2014:08:02 11:37:21

Comment: Thanks David. This seems like a good idea. It's a pity the description field doesn't get pulled into the .exif file created. My solution was hoping for something that could natively read the EXIF information and display it directly. Anyway some one decided this is a duplicate question, which it is not.

Comment: @user114644 looks like a duplicate to me?